# How to do color formatting of cell in excel based on multiple conditions

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I have two columns. One column has the tier as `Prime,essential,maintenance and Consumption`.
Other column has `values` in either `% or as NA`.
I want to format all cells which are having tier as Prime and essential and `value is >=90` as `green` else `Red`.
Similarly if tier is `maintenance or Consumption` and `value is >= 96` then `green else Red` .

How do i do it.
Please help

Answer (score 1):

1. Select the range that you will work with;
2. Click the Home > Conditional Formatting > New Rule….
3. In the Format Only Cells with section, specify the conditions that you need.
4. Click the Format button.
5. In the Format Cells dialog box, set the background color under Fill tab.

More details [here](http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/849-excel-change-background-color-based-on-cell-value.html#excel)

For your conditional formatting just select a column go to:

- **conditional formatting>highlight cells rules>less than** at the value you put **90** and at highlight you choose **red**

  then again:
- **conditional formatting>highlight cells rules>greater than** and at the value you put **89** and at color **green**

**UPDATE:**

For more conditions go to new rule and choose **use a formula**. The formula will look like this for the green color: `=AND(A1="Prime",B1>90)` then you do the same steps for the other conditions and colors.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your Response. However it would be great if you write the formula as well. I am little new to this formatting and knows only Basic rules :(

Comment: @Ratna No problem, it was useful for me two. Please accept the answer to close the question.

Comment: @Ratna now it would be more easy for you.

Comment: But what about the Tier condition as Prime Essential n etc.. ?

Comment: can you put a sketch of the table?

Comment: I have updated the response, this should be enough for you to continue.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, all cells will be one or other colour, which means only one colour need be set by Conditional Formatting. (The other can be applied with 'standard' fill, leaving the CF rule to override it where applicable).

It might be easier to fill 'standard' with green and use CF for red but the formula rule for green (ie formatting the whole range red with standard fill) might be:

```
=OR(AND(OR($A1="Prime",$A1="essential"),$B1>=0.9,NOT(ISTEXT($B1))),AND(OR($A1="maintenance",$A1="Consumption"),$B1>=0.96,NOT(ISTEXT($B1))))
```

This assumes the tiers are in ColumnA and the percentages are in ColumnB (where the value `1` represents `100%`, even if formatted to appear as `100%`). The Applies to range should be `=$A:$B` or a number of rows in those columns, to suit. The Applies to range may be set by selecting ColumnsA:B before entering the CF formula rule.